# Popup box is not disappearing properly with only single outside click, & yes also how can i create reverse transaction when its going to display none

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

plz help me by solving two problem with my this code

this Popup div box is not disappearing properly with only single outside click, & yes also how can i create reverse transaction when its going to display none

how can i create reverse transction when click on anywhere of page to dissapear this popup, & also this is not disappearing properly with only single outside click.

```js
function getSelected() {
    if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
    else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
    else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
/* create sniffer */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-textarea').mouseup(function(event) {
        var selection = getSelected();
        selection = $.trim(selection);
        if(selection != ''){
        $("span.popup-tag").css("display","block");
        $("span.popup-tag").css("top",event.clientY);
        $("span.popup-tag").css("left",event.clientX);
        $("span.popup-tag").text(selection);
        }else{
        $("span.popup-tag").css("display","none");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.popup-tag{
position:absolute;
display:none;
background-color:#785448d4;
color:white;
padding:10px;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:underline;
cursor:pointer;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 5000px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113,158,206,0.8));
}

.popup-tag{-webkit-animation:rotate-center .6s ease-in-out both;animation:rotate-center .6s ease-in-out both}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate-center{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes rotate-center{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

Select any text :<br>
<div type="text" id="my-textarea" style="width:100%; height:200px;" >
While delivering a lecture at the Indian Institute of Management Shillong, Kalam collapsed and died from an apparent cardiac arrest on 27 July 2015, aged 83. Thousands including national-level dignitaries attended the funeral ceremony held in his hometown of Rameshwaram, where he was buried with full state honours.
</div>

<span class="popup-tag"></span>
```

Any one can help me to make it solved.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, you're using the `display` property to hide/show the popup.
If I well understood your need, you want your popup to hide and show with an animation, played back and forth. So my suggestion is to add et remove a CSS class to your popup in order to get more control over the animation.

```js
function getSelected() {
    if(window.getSelection) { return window.getSelection(); }
    else if(document.getSelection) { return document.getSelection(); }
    else {
        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
if(selection.text) { return selection.text; }
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
/* create sniffer */
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#my-textarea').mouseup(function(event) {
        var selection = getSelected();
        selection = $.trim(selection);
        if(selection != ''){
        $("span.popup-tag").addClass('active');
        $("span.popup-tag").css("top",event.clientY);
        $("span.popup-tag").css("left",event.clientX);
        $("span.popup-tag").text(selection);
        }else{
        $("span.popup-tag").removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.popup-tag{
position:absolute;
display:none;
background-color:#785448d4;
color:white;
padding:10px;
font-size:20px;
font-weight:bold;
text-decoration:underline;
cursor:pointer;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 5000px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);

-webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(113,158,206,0.8));
}

.popup-tag {
  display:block;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate(-240deg);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.popup-tag.active {
  opacity: 100;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

Select any text :<br>
<div type="text" id="my-textarea" style="width:100%; height:200px;" >
While delivering a lecture at the Indian Institute of Management Shillong, Kalam collapsed and died from an apparent cardiac arrest on 27 July 2015, aged 83. Thousands including national-level dignitaries attended the funeral ceremony held in his hometown of Rameshwaram, where he was buried with full state honours.
</div>

<span class="popup-tag"></span>
```

Comment: its not working, can you explain it in detail with example ?

Comment: the transction is working perfect but, the popup box is not removing / disappearing properly with single outside click.

Comment: You have to be more specific regarding "properly". What is the exact behaviour expected? With the example I've provided, on click outside the popup, the animation play backward correctly. I edited the answer to show you a snippet

Comment: i understand your work on this animation, & Thanks for all that, But

Comment: many times the popup in not disappear with single click outside area of popup, what is the problem plz make it solve. Love U

Comment: Sorry Rakesh, but using Chrome, everytime I click outside the popup (on the black overlay) the popup disappears.

Comment: hello dear first of all, thanks a lot for giving me your valuabble time,

Comment: Ok I get it. But this is the expected behavior if you are selecting another part text. Instead of using box-shadow to make the black overlay, you can try to create a ::pseudo-element and also target it in js to remove the .active class on click.

Comment: okay thanks a lot for this help, 
can you help more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641855/how-to-get-view-selected-text-on-this-popup-so-this-can-be-view-that-what-t

Comment: hello dear  #jeremy_o plz can you help me for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62641855/how-to-get-view-selected-text-on-this-popup-so-this-can-be-view-that-what-t