# How to get / view selected text on this popup, ? so this can be view that what text is going to be share

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to get / view selected text on this popup, ? so this can be view that what text is going to be share.
Hello dear stackoverflow community, plz help me to make this solve
i want to show sharable text on this popup so that it can be view that what text is going to be share.
**my main purpose is that to display selected text on this popup div.**

```js
const selectableTextArea = document.querySelectorAll(".selectable-text-area");
const twitterShareBtn = document.querySelector("#twitter-share-btn");

selectableTextArea.forEach(elem => {
  elem.addEventListener("mouseup", selectableTextAreaMouseUp);
});

twitterShareBtn.addEventListener("click", twitterShareBtnClick);

document.addEventListener("mousedown", documentMouseDown);

function selectableTextAreaMouseUp(event) {
  setTimeout(() => { // In order to avoid some weird behavior...
    const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
    if(selectedText.length) { 
      const x = event.pageX;
      const y = event.pageY;
      const twitterShareBtnWidth = Number(getComputedStyle(twitterShareBtn).width.slice(0,-2));
      const twitterShareBtnHeight = Number(getComputedStyle(twitterShareBtn).height.slice(0,-2));

      if(document.activeElement !== twitterShareBtn) {
        twitterShareBtn.style.left = `${x - twitterShareBtnWidth*0.5}px`;
        twitterShareBtn.style.top = `${y - twitterShareBtnHeight*1.25}px`;
        twitterShareBtn.style.display = "block";
        twitterShareBtn.classList.add("btnEntrance");
      }
      else {
        twitterShareBtn.style.left = `${x-twitterShareBtnWidth*0.5}px`;
        twitterShareBtn.style.top = `${y-twitterShareBtnHeight*0.5}px`;
      }
    }    
  }, 0);
}

function documentMouseDown(event) {
  if(event.target.id!=="twitter-share-btn" && getComputedStyle(twitterShareBtn).display==="block") {
    twitterShareBtn.style.display = "none";
    twitterShareBtn.classList.remove("btnEntrance");
    window.getSelection().empty();
  }
}

function twitterShareBtnClick(event) {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString().trim();
  if(selectedText.length) {
    // General Twitter Share URL: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text={title}&url={url}&hashtags={hash_tags}&via={user_id}
    const twitterShareUrl = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet";
    const text = `${encodeURIComponent(selectedText)}`;
    const currentUrl = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
    const hashtags = "helloworld, test, testing";
    const via = "CodingJrney";
    window.open(`${twitterShareUrl}?text="${text}"&url=${currentUrl}&hashtags=${hashtags}&via=${via}`);
    
    // Alternatively, we could include everything in the "text" field -> more room to customize the tweet:
    // window.open(`${twitterShareUrl}?text="${text}" by @${via} ${hashtags.split(",").map(h => "%23"+h.trim()).join(" ")} ${currentUrl}`);
    
    // We could also specify new window features:
    // const newWindowOptions = "height=400,width=550,top=0,left=0,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes";
    // window.open(`${twitterShareUrl}?text="${text}"&url=${currentUrl}&hashtags=${hashtags}&via=${via}`, "ShareOnTwitter", newWindowOptions);
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}
.container {
  padding: 1.5rem 10rem;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin: 1.25rem 0;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
hr {
  margin: 3rem 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)); 
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  line-height: 1.75rem;
}
#twitter-share-btn {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #56b8f5;
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #56b8f5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: none;
  transition: color 0.2s, background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 5000px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
#twitter-share-btn:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #56b8f5;
}
#twitter-share-btn i {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.btnEntrance {
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-name: btnEntrance;
}
@keyframes btnEntrance { /* zoomIn */
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }    
}

@media(max-width: 992px) {
  .container { padding: 1.25rem 6rem; }
  h1 { font-size: 2.5rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 1.75rem; }
}
@media(max-width:768px) {
  html { font-size: 12px; }
  .container { padding: 1rem 3rem; }
  h1 { font-size: 2rem; }
  h2 { font-size: 1.5rem; }
  hr { margin: 1.5rem 0; }
}
```

```html
<h2 class="selectable-text-area">Select the text you want to share</h2>
  <hr>
  <div class="selectable-text-area">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae pariatur eos aperiam saepe, beatae necessitatibus exercitationem, nemo, sit provident possimus debitis modi eligendi repellat iure vitae perferendis? Recusandae accusamus placeat velit itaque quis fuga laudantium debitis, ab eaque voluptatum illo esse incidunt! Quia tempore explicabo sint laboriosam rerum nihil voluptates voluptatibus voluptate iure. Earum magnam blanditiis voluptates quod ex exercitationem reiciendis, iure qui ducimus similique impedit nemo est, quisquam facere id adipisci harum tenetur consequuntur illum saepe laudantium. Suscipit facilis corporis natus aperiam! Reprehenderit hic quia natus nisi similique quod fugiat, architecto autem deleniti unde commodi accusamus modi voluptate?</p>
    
  </div>
</div>
<div id="twitter-share-btn">Share This on Twitter: _ _"here i want to show that what text is going to share (means selected text)" _ _</div>
```

thanks in advance.
my main purpose is that to display selected text on this popup div.

Comment: `twitterShareBtn.textContent = selectedText;`

Comment: Hello Dear  Yousaf, plz explain a littel detail, share example plzzzz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the selected text as text content of the pop-up element using either `innerHTML` or `textContent` property.

See the following example code snippet.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.selectable-text-area');
const popupContainer = document.querySelector('.popupContainer');

container.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  if (selectedText) {
    showPopup(selectedText);
  }
});

popupContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches('.popupContainer')) {
    popupContainer.classList.remove('show');
  }
});

function showPopup(selectedText) {
  // set the selected text as html inside popup element
  document.querySelector('.popup').innerHTML = selectedText;
  popupContainer.classList.add('show');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.selectable-text-area {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.popupContainer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  top: 0;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}

.popup {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectable-text-area">
  <p>plz help me to make this solve i want to show sharable text on this popup so that it can be view that what text is going to be share. my main purpose is that to display selected text on this popup div</p>
</div>

<div class="popupContainer">
  <div class="popup"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a Lot, Love You

Comment: Hello Dear #Yousaf one problem is there, that is how to prevent to close popup when we click inside of popup, i want close the popup only when we click on anywhere outside of popup.

Comment: Thanks a Lot Love You Bro